# Cloud Linux 7 mount /tmp with exec in fstab

Tags: fstab, cloudlinux

I have the following fstab

```
UUID=3d301281-7be7-4a53-8f19-42f8c7d061d2       /       xfs     defaults,uquota 0 0

#/usr/swpDSK    swap    swap    defaults        0 0
#/usr/tmpDSK    /tmp    ext3    defaults,noauto 0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto,exec        0 0
/var/swap.1   swap    swap    defaults        0   0
```

However when I reboot my /tmp looks like this

```
/usr/tmpDSK on /tmp type ext4 (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

If I do:

`sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec`. It looks like the below

```
/usr/tmpDSK on /tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

What do I put in fstab so it does NOT have noexec on reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do (in this case, as /tmp directories default to have noexec set), is to allow it to mount with noexec set, then add the command `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` in rc.local which executes after /etc/fstab.

Comment: If this question has helped you, please do award the bounty for the question.